# Mule InstallException: Config for app not found

Tags: mule

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" 
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
    xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" 
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" 
    xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" 
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="dev.properties" />
```

And dev.properties is in /src/main/resources

Works in Studio but not in Mule stand alone

Comment: will be hard to help you with this info..

Would you mind to provide the stacktrace and some additional info. Are you using maven ?

Answer (score 0):

After deployment in standalone, cross check in your server dev.properties file present in /opt/{mule.}/apps/{your apps}/classes/properties/dev.properties.

or If project maintained all the properties in config folder cross check in the following location /conf/dev.properties

make sure defined envt in either in mule-app.properties or passing in runtime.

Refer:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/deploying-to-multiple-environments